# How do i access all my google maps markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am not seeing it i'll think if one of you looks at it can immediately tell me what i have to do. Now i resize my marker but it only takes the last marker of the array.

here the code I'll loop trough the array of object markers:

```
var locations = [
    [{id: 1, lat: 51.523229192354066, lng: 5.139241042480535, content: 'Title A'}],
    [{id: 2, lat: 51.52309568310267, lng:  5.139251771316594, content: 'Title B'}],
    [{id: 3, lat: 51.5229888754197, lng:  5.139434161529607, content: 'Title C'}],
    [{id: 4, lat: 51.52284868995566,  lng:  5.139487805709905, content: 'Title D'}],
    [{id: 5, lat: 51.522715179588666,  lng:  5.139670195922918, content: 'Title E'}],
    [{id: 6, lat: 51.52258166883027,  lng:  5.1397989419556325, content: 'Title F'}],
    [{id: 7, lat: 51.52242813097418,  lng:  5.139927687988347, content: 'Title G'}],
    [{id: 8, lat: 51.52227793039666,  lng:   5.139927687988347, content: 'Title H'}],
    [{id: 9, lat: 51.522625059869696, lng:     5.138688507423467, content: 'Title I'}]
];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var myLatLng = {lat: locations[i][0].lat, lng: locations[i][0].lng};

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        icon: icon1,
        map: map
    });


    map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
        if (map.getZoom() === 17) {
            marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(32, 32);
            marker.icon.size = new google.maps.Size(32, 32);
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
        if (map.getZoom() === 18) {
            console.log(marker[i]);
            marker.icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(90, 90);
            marker.icon.size = new google.maps.Size(90, 90);
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    });
```

If i try to access marker[i].icon it is undefined. Please can somebody help me out to use size ALL the markers.

Here is a fiddle for a better view zoom in and out to see what happens only one marker change in size:
https://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/a8z0yyeq/10/

Comment: Because it's not array `marker`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this: you're looping over all your markers, adding a new event listener for the map's zoom_changed event.  In each of those event listeners, you're referring to the variable `marker`.  This event listener function doesn't get executed at the moment you define it, it only happens when the zoom changes obviously.  So at that point, the variable `marker` will equal whatever it was at the very last iteration of your for loop.

Instead you need to change how you setup this event listener, something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var myLatLng = {lat: locations[i][0].lat, lng: locations[i][0].lng};

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        icon: icon1,
        map: map
    });

    setMarkerSize(marker);
}

function setMarkerSize(marker) {
    var icon = marker.icon;
    map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
        if (map.getZoom() === 16) {
            icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(15, 15);
            icon.size = new google.maps.Size(15, 15);
            marker.setIcon(icon);
            console.log(marker.icon.size);
        }
        if (map.getZoom() === 17) {
            icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(32, 32);
            icon.size = new google.maps.Size(32, 32);
            marker.setIcon(icon);
            console.log(marker.icon.size);
        }
        if (map.getZoom() === 18) {
            icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(90, 90);
            icon.size = new google.maps.Size(90, 90);
            marker.setIcon(icon);
            console.log(marker.icon.size);
        }
    });
}
```

In this case, `marker` inside the `setMarkerSize` function is a local variable that will be different each time you call the function.

Comment: Can you maybe edit it in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/a8z0yyeq/10/ 
Because it is not working with me

Comment: If i log it i see the right size in console, but the icon is not changing size.

Comment: where do you create `icon1`?  You might need to use `marker.setIcon(...)` with a new icon using the size & scaledSize you need, instead of just adjusting the properties directly on the marker's current icon.

Comment: It works with marker.setIcon(....) Thanks. But i want to create one variable of icon and than resize that one for cleaner code..\

Comment: you could create two variables using `icon1` as the origin, setting the relevant sizes, that you then refer to in the setMarkerSize function

Comment: I need the code of marker.icon.size = .... because i am checking the id's of the markers to set an other image to it because some of them are rotated houses, to match the map. And if i do it like setIcon(..) all of them change to that image.

Comment: As you can see it is logging => https://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/a8z0yyeq/15/ but not resizing. Can you please help me out here

Comment: Can you please help me out here @duncan

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer I've updated the setMarker function in my answer to a way that worked for me. Create a variable in your function, set its size and scaledSize values, then pass it to `marker.setIcon()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108266/discussion-between-beginnerprogrammer-and-duncan).

Comment: can you come in chat again?